# Detecting all the pixels in a hexagon with JS/HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, geometry

In javascript I have a map that I'd like to overlay with hexes and turn those hexes either green (land) or blue (water) based on how much land is in the hex. 
I assume that it has something to do with detecting the pixel color and if it is in a range that I consider blue then it gets counted as "water" once it reaches a certain number of pixels that are water, it just turns into a water tile.

The Problem I am having is that I know I have to define where to scan for all the pixels I want to color detect but I don't know how to do that with a hex. With a square grid i could do a nest for loop, but no clue how to do it with a hex.

To draw the hex I am using the following

```
    function hex(x = 0, y = 0, side = 0, size = 10) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x + size * Math.cos(0), y + size * Math.sin(0));

    for (side; side < 7; side++) {
        ctx.lineTo(x + size * Math.cos(side * 2 * Math.PI / 6), y + size * Math.sin(side * 2 * Math.PI / 6));
    }
}
```

But I don't see how I could use this for determining which pixels to detect. I'm not good at the maths.

Comment: _“I'm not good at the maths”_ - well then get better, and/or do proper research. In the form this is right now, this is simply too broad. Suggest you start with circles instead of hexagons (for the measuring of the pixels, not the final display) - determining what pixels fall into a circle is easier, than doing the same thing for a hexagon.

Comment: If I knew how to figure this out beyond what i have said I wouldn't ask. You comment is neither helpful nor informative. I've already spent a while looking for and trying to figure out the answer and I couldn't find anything to help.

Comment: Then you need to work on your basic research skills as well. Typing something like [“what is the math to check if a point is inside hexagon” into Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20the%20math%20to%20check%20if%20a%20point%20is%20inside%20hexagon) gives you plenty of approaches already.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan hex line by line like rectangle. But your inner loop should vary its limits.

Your hex is flat-top, for (0,0)-centered hex left top vertex has coordinates `(-side/2, -side * Sqrt(3)/2)`. Let `p = Sqrt(3)/2`.

So outer (y-coordinate) loop limits are

```
  -side * p .. side * p
```

For given y-coordinate x-limits are

```
-(side - 0.5 * Abs(y)) / p  .. (side - 0.5 * Abs(y)) / p
```

Delphi code:

```
var
  ix, iy, side: Integer;
  cf: Double;
begin
  cf := Sqrt(3) / 2;
  side := 100;
  for iy :=  - Round(cf * side) to Round(cf * side) do
     for ix := - Round((side - 0.5 * Abs(iy) / cf)) to
                 Round((side - 0.5 * Abs(iy) / cf)) do
         Canvas.Pixels[ix + 200, iy + 200] := clBlue;
```

generates

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that...I've never used delphi code. It looks like you're using a 2 for loops and just painting the pixels in the hex blue as you go... is that right? Is "side" meant to be "size" and 200 supposed to be the offset from the side?

Comment: As far as I understand - your problem is to check all pixels inside some hexagon.I walk through all pixels inside hexagon and paint them only for demonstration. 200 is just shift to place hex in screen center. Yes, side=size

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. Question, do you know if stepping through in your way is worse or better than the JS/canvas shape fill method of coloring in? I need to have a grid of 266x533 and that many hexes kills my browser ^.^ Just wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it

Comment: If you need to **check every pixel** of every hex - it is the most efficient way. If you need to **draw filled hexes** - polygon graphic primitives are better.